# Computed Twig - Parsing Date(d-m-Y)

Tags: twig, drupal-8, drupal-webform

Using the following computed value/markup in webform field

```
{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:start_date]', webform_submission) }}
```

Correctly, it gives: 02-08-2016

Now, I need to parse the string to a date object.

I tried both of these:

```
{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:start_date]', webform_submission)| date("d/m/Y") }}

 {{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:start_date]', webform_submission)| date("d-m-Y") }}
```

And I got the same error message:

> Computed value/markup is not valid.
>   An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ([webform_submission:values:start_date]) at position 0 ([): Unexpected character") in "{# inline_template_start #}{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:start_date]', webform_submission)| date("d/m/Y") }}" at line 1.

Comment: try surrounding with `()`  as  `{{ (webform_token('[webform_submission:values:start_date]', webform_submission))| date("d-m-Y") }}`

Comment: See also [this issue here](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2941314)